# mockito simulate test exception thrown by service

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito, jmockit

I am trying to test exception thrown from service when I use the instance of it.
Like I am trying to use Imock in Trans.class and use IMock method.
Below is the code

```
public class MockImpl implements IMock{
    public String external(String str) throws Exception {
        if(str.equals("throw")){
            throw new Exception("Thrown exception.");
        }
        return str;
    }
}

public class Trans {
    private IMock mc;
    public static int failed;

    public String performTrans(String str) throws Exception {

        return call(str);

    }

    private String call(String str) throws Exception {
        mc = new MockImpl();
        try {
            return mc.external(str);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            failed++;
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

In test class I am trying to do this

```
public class TestMock {

    @Test
    public void testMock() throws Exception {
        Trans trans = mock(Trans.class);
        IMock iMock = mock(IMock.class);

        doThrow(new Exception()).when(iMock).external(any(String.class));

        for(int i =0;i<10 ;i++){
            trans.performTrans("any");
        }
        System.out.println(Trans.failed);
        assertEquals(9, Trans.failed);
    }

}
```

As I am new to this, I am not sure if my understanding is correct, what I am trying to achieve is
When I do # Trans.performTrans(String);
Then doThrow(new Exception()).when(iMock).external(any(String.class)); should happen. **How can I tell Mockito or any test framework that The exception should be thrown should be simulated from the Imock service method, even if it is indirectly called.**

**UPDATE**

After trying to test this way
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestMock {

```
@Test
public void testMock() throws Exception {
   Trans trans = new Trans();
   IMock iMock = mock(IMock.class);

   trans.setInter(iMock);

    //doThrow(new Exception()).when(iMock).external(any(String.class));

    trans.performTrans("abc");
    verify(iMock).external(new String("a"));

    System.out.println(Trans.failed);
    assertEquals(9, Trans.failed);
}
```

}

I get this error.

> Wanted but not invoked: iMock.external("a");
> -> at com.app.TestMock.testMock(TestMock.java:32) Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

what could be wrong?

Comment: 1. What is trans.setInter. Do you still create new imock in trans.call? 2. abc is not equal to a.

Comment: this does not appear to be a question about the jmockit testing framework.  Looks pretty mockito to me.